# Simulate touchstart event on newly created view (similar to iOS Calendar app)

Tags: ios, titanium, touch-event

I am basically trying to do the same thing on iOS that is done in the iOS Calendar app when it comes to create a new event by pressing the screen long: In this case, as most of you know, a new view is created and you can immediately (without releasing the finger) drag this new view and drop it on the cell representing the day that you want to add the event to.

Is this possible with Titanium? My understanding is that I somehow have to manually trigger some sort of touch event on the new view, but how can this be done?

I tried to implement this by firing a touchstart event on the new view right after having created it, but that doesn't seem to be the right solution:

```
var Draggable = require('ti.draggable');

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#fff'
});

win1.addEventListener("longpress", function(e) {
    Ti.API.info(e.type + " event: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    var newEvent = Draggable.createView({
        id : "newEvent",
        center : {
            x : e.x,
            y : e.y
        },
        width : 80,
        height : 20,
        backgroundColor : "#3498db"
    });
    win1.add(newEvent);
    newEvent.addEventListener("start", function(e) {
        Ti.API.info(e.type + " event: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    });

    newEvent.fireEvent("start", e);
});

win1.open();
```

Note that I am using the [TiDraggable module](https://github.com/animecyc/TiDraggable/releases) for draggable views.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Thanks,
Thomas